# Jooq resolves unnest / table to union all (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, jooq, unnest

I'm using jOOQ to delete a variable number of rows from an Oracle database:

```java
List<Integer> ids = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4);

db.deleteFrom(MESSAGE)
    .where(MESSAGE.ID.in(ids))
    .execute();
```

However, this means that a variable number of bind variables is used. This leads to the problem that [Oracle always does a hard parse](https://blog.jooq.org/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster/).

I have tried using the `unnest` or `table` function to create a statement with only one bind variable. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. jOOQ creates statements with multiple bind variables and `union all` statements:

```java
db.deleteFrom(MESSAGE)
    .where(MESSAGE.ID.in(
        select(field("*", Long.class))
            .from(table(ids))
    ))
    .execute();
```

```
LoggerListener       DEBUG - Executing query          : delete from "MESSAGE" where "MESSAGE"."ID" in (select * from ((select ? "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select ? "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select ? "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select ? "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual)) "array_table")
LoggerListener       DEBUG - -> with bind values      : delete from "MESSAGE" where "MESSAGE"."ID" in (select * from ((select 1 "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select 2 "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select 3 "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual) union all (select 4 "COLUMN_VALUE" from dual)) "array_table")
```

The [javadoc of the unnest function](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#unnest(java.util.Collection)) recommends using the `table` function for Oracle

> Create a table from an array of values.
>
> This is equivalent to the TABLE function for H2, or the UNNEST function in HSQLDB and Postgres
>
> For Oracle, use table(ArrayRecord) instead, as Oracle knows only typed arrays
>
> In all other dialects, unnesting of arrays is emulated using several UNION ALL connected subqueries.

Altough I use the `table` function, I still get the emulated UNION ALL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `TABLE` operator specifics

Oracle's `TABLE(collection)` function doesn't accept arbitrary arrays, only SQL table types, such as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t AS TABLE OF NUMBER
```

You could create such a type and use the code generator to create a `TRecord`, which you could pass to that `TABLE` operator:

```java
from(table(new TRecord(ids)))
```

Unfortunately, such a type is required in Oracle. In its absence, the `UNION ALL` emulation seems to be the best way, but that doesn't solve your problem.

> Note the `TABLE` operator has its own caveats, mainly that it produces poor cardinality estimates, so for small tables, it may not be the best choice. Though, do measure yourself! [I've documented this here in a blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster/)

### Avoiding cursor cache contention

jOOQ has a nice feature called [`IN` list padding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-in-list-padding/), which mitigates most of the dynamic SQL problems that arise from such hard parses. In short, it prevents arbitrary `IN` list sizes by repeating the last element to pad the list up to 2^n elements, getting you:

```sql
id IN (?)                      -- For 1 element
id IN (?, ?)                   -- For 2 elements
id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)             -- For 3-4 elements
id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) -- For 5-8 elements
```

It's a hack for when the `TABLE` operator is too complex. It works by reducing the number of possible predicates logarithmically, which might just be good enough.

### Other alternatives

You can always also use:

- Temp tables, and batch insert the IDs in there
- Use an actual semi join: `ID IN (SELECT original_id FROM original_table)` (this is usually the best approach, if possible)